# Windows encountered recovery code error 0x000000428 after installing alongside Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

hey i am trying to dual boot Windows 11 and Ubuntu 64bit but then Windows gets an error which is recovery code 0x000000428.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: This is an Ubuntu question & answer site. Better to use Windows forum or other StackExchange sites for Windows issues. Is error from UEFI boot of Windows. Then just a Windows issue. If from grub attempting to boot Windows, you need to turn bitlocker & fast startup off in Windows. Linux NTFS driver cannot see hibernated nor encrypted partitions.